# scrollbar in grid in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

My code is that:

```
    ScrollContainer.Content = grid;
    Content = ScrollContainer;
    Content.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
```

[screen 1 i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMxMZ.jpg)

I want to have scrollbar in the right side:

[screen i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN3b5.jpg)

I try set `Content.HorizontalOptions` as `LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand` but it not help me (result such as screen 1). Also I try set `Content.HorizontalOptions` as `LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand:` scrollbar is ok, but grid in not center and `grid.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center` not helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `Padding` tou your `ScrollContainer` so that the scrollbar have some distance between the end and your Grid.

Comment: thanks, it is good) Did you know is it possible to set the padding to the screen edges are not calculating the value manually (distance from right cell and right side screen)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what your current layout looks like but I'll improvise.

You can probably achieve your desired layout in 100 different ways. Every time you make a ScrollView you should also consider the usability of the interface - small screens, touch screens, shrunk window... and if possible - avoid it. Especially if the contents are static, which the Grid hints at.

If you need a scroll view and you expect your scroll contents to be scrollable as a normal part of your UX then you should **consider using a ListView or some other dynamic layout instead**.

Here's a couple options in pseudo-XAML:

```
<ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <Grid HorizontalOptions="Start"> <!-- this should move the Grid in the left part of the Scroll
    <Grid.Columns>
      <Column Width="100"/>
      <Column Width="100"/>
      <Column Width="100"/>
    </Grid.Columns>



<ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Columns>
      <Column Width="100"/>
      <Column Width="100"/>
      <Column Width="100"/>
      <Column Width="*"/> <!-- one extra column with Width to take the remaining space-->
   ...
```

Answer (score -1):

set the grid in stacklayout after that 
set Padding to distance between the end and your Grid.

```
StackLayout Scroller = new StackLayout { 
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0),
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Spacing = 375 / 100 + 10,
        };

        ScrollView Scroll = new ScrollView { 
            Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
        };

        Scroll.Content = Scroller;
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how the code would look like using this answer ?

Comment: StackLayout Scroller = new StackLayout { 
                Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0),
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Spacing = 375 / 100 + 10,
            };

            ScrollView Scroll = new ScrollView { 
                Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
            };

            Scroll.Content = Scroller;